# Accessing a resource with getResourceAsStream()

Tags: java, android, resources, android-resources, getresource

Having some trouble doing a simple json file read in an Android project. The following code is in the static method CalendarActivity.getCredentials().

```
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "credentials.json";

InputStream in = CalendarActivity.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
if (in == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
}
```

My understanding is that my file credentials.json should be in the same folder as the CalendarActivity class. I've tried this but getResourceAsStream() returns null. I've also tried putting it in my /res/ folder, without success. How can I access my file?

My code structure is:

```
src/main/java/com/team33/meetingmate/CalendarActivity.java
src/main/java/com/team33/meetingmate/credentials.json
src/main/res/
```

Comment: btw why do you want to get `InputStream` using `getResourceAsStream`? why not using `AssetManager` for example?

Comment: Adding / still returns null... no particular reason just following a java code sample...

Comment: so use `AssetManager`

Comment: I tried to use AssetManager but for some reason I'm getting an OutOfMemoryError when calling getAssets()